# REGEX Find string in path and exclude part of string

Tags: regular-expression

Hopefully this is an easy one.  I am using the `REG_EXTRACT` in Informatica to extract a file name from a variable.  It uses regex to identify what to extract. Here is my example.
This is my file name with file path as it comes into powercenter.

```
FILENAME=/test_files/infa_test/nippy/SrcFiles/JUNK/JUNK_OPS_SPINK_PAE_01-01-01-01-01-99.csv
REG_EXTRACT($FILENAME,'^\/(.+\/)*(.+)$',2).
```

The produces `JUNK_OPS_SPINK_PAE_01-01-01-01-01-99.csv`.  I'm having a hard time writing the regex argument to only extract the file_name after JUNK/ but before _SPINK like 'JUNK_OPS'.  The underscores vary from file to file but '_SPINK' will always appear after what I need to extract. Any help would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this maybe:

```
^.*\/(.*)_SPINK.*$
```

Unfortunately, I don't have access to Informatica to test it, but `sed` agrees:

```
echo '/test_files/infa_test/nippy/SrcFiles/JUNK/JUNK_OPS_SPINK_PAE_01-01-01-01-01-99.csv' |
sed -E 's/^.*\/(.*)_SPINK.*$/\1/'
```

This produces `JUNK_OPS`.

Depending on how `REG_EXTRACT` works, it may be shortened to

```
\/([^/]*)_SPINK
```

Comment: The shorter version doesn't work but your 1st answer does.

Comment: @mrlddst Well, that's good. The second variation was just a "test it and see what happens" kind of thing.